# Windows 8/2012 Change Menu and other colors

Tags: windows, windows-8, colors, themes, windows-server-2012

Is there a way to change the background color of menus in Windows 8 or the highlight color when you roll over a menu?

I looked and I can't seem to find a way to do it. Do I need to install something else